# "mount error(13): Permission denied" only in LXC container for CIFS/Samba share

Tags: ubuntu, samba, mount, cifs, lxc

I have a samba share that mounts just fine under the Ubuntu 12.04 host:

```
root:~# mount -t cifs -o credentials=/var/lib/lxc/vpn/rootfs/etc/samba/desktop.credentials //desktop/Media /media/Media
```

But when I try to do the same mount in an LXC container, also Ubuntu 12.04, which also has the `cifs-utils` package installed, I get a permission error:

```
root:~# mount -t cifs -o credentials=/etc/samba/desktop.credentials //desktop/Media  /media/Media
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Both commands are being run as root.  Why would this be different in the container and is there a way I can get this mount to work under the container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direct mounting is not possible, you should mount the share to the host first and then use `lxc.mount.entry` configuration directive to bind mount share's mountpoint inside the container (an example of using `lxc.mount.entry` can be found [here](http://monotrematica.blogspot.com/2012/02/binding-host-directories-to-container.html)). You can also provide the container with an external fstab file as shown [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1476832).